# Disadvantages of having Tomcat execute HTML-files as JSP code

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

we maintain an Apache Tomcat for a customer which is connected to a regular Apache Webserver using an AJP-bridge. At some point in the past the customer requested that the content-type response header always contains "charset=utf-8" which was implemented by the following configuration in the Tomcat:

```
<jsp-config>
   <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Just recently we realized this leads to HTML-files being executed as if they were JSP-files which we want to avoid and instead configure the response header using `<mime-mapping>`. Unfortunately the above configuration has been on production servers for over a year now and the customer asked for why we want to change the configuration.

Our initial suggestions of abiding by the principle of least privilege, potentially higher delivery times and increased chances of cross-site scripting only lead to further questions for details. Due to lack of experience with these matters I'm hoping to get some feedback here.

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: "When a JSP is requested for the first time or when the webapp starts up, the servlet container will compile the JSP file into a class extending HttpServlet and use it during the webapp's lifetime." from chapter Lifecycle of SO JSP Wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpretting HTML as JSP files means that:

- `<% ... %>` will be interpretted as Java code
- `<%@ %>` will be interpretted as JSP directives
- `<taglib:tag />` will be interpretted as JSP tags
- `${}` will be interpretted as EL expressions

Writing these in the HTML can lead to an exception or unintentional code execution. Now it depends on who can edit the HTML files. If they are edited via CMS, this is a pretty **SEVERE security issue**.

If you want to force encoding, it is done via either servlet filter (see [`CharacterEncodingFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html)), Tomcat valve ([nothing usable in default](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html) package) or via [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) or [`AddDefaultCharset`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) configuration in your Apache HTTP server.

Almost any solution would be better, cleaner, simpler and safer than what you did :).